# Validate.JS - DISallow Non-ASCII Unicode Characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, unicode

I'm looking for a Regex, or easy function that returns TRUE/FALSE, that detects the presence of Non-ASCII Unicode Characters, to be used in my `$("form").validate({` call. Basically, if the user enters any unicode characters, I want the validation to fail. I want to allow all standard, SQL-VARCHAR-acceptable, characters.

Comment: This is purely for First/Last Name validations, so issues about unicode numbers and whatnot do not apply.

Comment: You know, ASCII characters are Unicode characters too. I think you meant to ask about non-ASCII Unicode characters.

Comment: You are, of course, correct, and I'll make an edit to the question so that it's more helpful to those who follow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use this regex:

```
var re = /[^\x00-\x7f]/;
```

then use it as:

```
var invalid = re.test(name);
// true if there is any character beyond ASCII (128) is present
```

Comment: Fantastic. Exactly what was asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).

```
for(var i = 0, l = string.length; i < l; i++) {
    if(string.charCodeAt(i) > 127) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: If I could accept two answers, I'd check this one, but it was sort of a "first come" sort of thing.

Comment: @PKD No need to explain your vote; just make sure you chose the one you think is more useful. It shouldn't matter who posted first.

Comment: They're both pretty damned useful, and well-written. In the end, I went for "short and sweet", but I appreciate the knowledge inherent in both, and I've starred this Question so I can keep it for KB use later. Thanks!